# Como usar CSS para cortar texto ao encontrar um caractere específico?

Tags: css, webkit

Como usar CSS ou `webkit` para cortar texto ao encontrar um caractere específico?

Por exemplo... o texto seguinte:

> "O sucesso do juiz Sérgio Moro é tanto que uma agência de turismo do estado do Paraná criou um pacote que visa atrair clientes com rotas da Operação Lava Jato. Segundo a coluna de Mônica Bergamo, do jornal Folha de S. Paulo, o pacote leva as pessoas para conhecerem os locais onde se desenrolam as investigações, na cidade de Curitiba. O roteiro dura cinco horas e os turistas visitam a Procuradoria-Geral da República e depois aos locais onde o juiz Sergio Moro, da 13ª Vara Federal frequenta: a Universidade Federal do Paraná, "onde leciona", e a sede da Justiça Federal."

Gostaria de cortar quando encontrasse o primeiro ponto `.`. Ficaria assim:

> "O sucesso do juiz Sérgio Moro é tanto que uma agência de turismo do estado do Paraná criou um pacote que visa atrair clientes com rotas da Operação Lava Jato."

Isso é possível?

Comment: Não é caso de CSS.

Comment: Com CSS não tem como fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Cara CSS serve apenas para "dar beleza".

No caso um processamento mais afinco assim acho que deveria usar uma linguagem back ou o javascript. a maioria das linguagens (para não dizer todas) tem uma função chamada "split" onde voce delimita a onde quer quebrar uma determinada string, no caso vc quebraria nesse ponto, o split te retorna uma matriz, entao teoricamente esse trecho referente ao primeiro ponto ficaria na posição 0. 
Segue exemplo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "O sucesso do juiz Sérgio Moro é tanto que uma agência de turismo do estado do Paraná criou um pacote que visa atrair clientes com rotas da Operação Lava Jato. Segundo a coluna de Mônica Bergamo, do jornal Folha de S. Paulo, o pacote leva as pessoas para conhecerem os locais onde se desenrolam as investigações, na cidade de Curitiba. O roteiro dura cinco horas e os turistas visitam a Procuradoria-Geral da República e depois aos locais onde o juiz Sergio Moro, da 13ª Vara Federal frequenta: a Universidade Federal do Paraná, onde leciona, e a sede da Justiça Federal.";

    var res = str.split(".");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[0];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```